# Magento 2 Add customer Billing Phone number column in Order and Invoice grid. I also want to filter and search with this phone number

Tags: magento2

Magento 2 Add customer Billing Phone number column in Order and Invoice grid. I also want to filter and search with this phone number. 
Please provide code if anyone have done this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First you need to add column through uicomponent

`app\code\Vendor\Module\view\adminhtml\ui_component\sales_order_grid.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
<columns name="sales_order_columns">
    <column name="telephone">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Phone Number</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">6</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </column>
 </columns>
 </listing>
```

then Add the collection file in your module

`Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Grid\Collection.php`

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Grid;

use Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Grid\Collection as OriginalCollection;

/**
 * Order grid extended collection
 */
class Collection extends OriginalCollection
{

    protected function _initSelect()
    {
        $this->addFilterToMap('status', 'main_table.status');
        $this->addFilterToMap('customer_id', 'main_table.customer_id');

        parent::_initSelect();
    }

    protected function _renderFiltersBefore()
    {
    $joinTable = $this->getTable('sales_order_address');
    $this->getSelect()->joinLeft($joinTable, "main_table.entity_id = 
    {$joinTable}.parent_id AND {$joinTable}.address_type = 'billing'", 
      ['telephone']);
       parent::_renderFiltersBefore();
   }
    
}
```

At last Add `di.xml` in your module

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
 <type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory">
 <arguments>
 <argument name="collections" xsi:type="array">
 <item name="sales_order_grid_data_source" xsi:type="string">Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Grid\Collection</item>
 </argument>
 </arguments>
 </type>
</config>
```

It will add `customer billing phone number in order grid with filter`. I wrote this code it is my tested code. **I hope this will help**

Comment: Will this work for Search by keyword also ?

Comment: Check the screenshot: https://www.screencast.com/t/UGSHyQMKaG it will look like this. Text field filter because some times people added + in phone number as well it work on phone number column field

Comment: @Mohitchauhan if my answer helpful to you and fulfill to your need please mark my answer correct and upvote my answer so it helps others as well. keep coding :) thanks :)

Comment: Filter is working fine. but Search by keyword is not working.

Comment: @Mohitchauhan you want to phone number filter and column. It added filter and column I don't get what do you mean by `search by keyword` and why it is needed?

Comment: @MuhammadHasham what are the changes in JOIN if I want to add both billing and shipping telephone show in the sales order grid?

Comment: Thank you for this solution, but after applying it, order list toolbar disappears in administration (tested it in magento 2..3.1)

Answer (score 1):

The above Answer is perfect, But is not work when both billing and shipping address required, Some vendors require both billing and shipping addresses details in order grid then follow this join collection code.

```
protected function _initSelect()
{
    $this->addFilterToMap('billing_telephone', 'soa.telephone');
    $this->addFilterToMap('shipping_telephone', 'soa1.telephone');
    parent::_initSelect();
}
protected function _renderFiltersBefore()
{
    $this->getSelect()->joinLeft(
        ['soa' => 'sales_order_address'],
        "main_table.entity_id =soa.parent_id AND soa.address_type = 'billing'",
        ['billing_telephone'=>'soa.telephone']
    );

    $this->getSelect()->joinLeft(
        ['soa1' => 'sales_order_address'],
        "main_table.entity_id =soa1.parent_id AND soa1.address_type = 'shipping'",
        ['shipping_telephone'=>'soa1.telephone']
    );

    parent::_renderFiltersBefore();
}
```

and In **sales_order_grid.xml**

```
<column name="billing_telephone">
        <settings>
            <filter>text</filter>
            <label translate="true">Billing Telephone</label>
        </settings>
    </column>

    <column name="shipping_telephone">
        <settings>
            <filter>text</filter>
            <label translate="true">Shipping Telephone</label>
        </settings>
    </column>
```

It renders correct values and is filterable, it tested on **magento 2.4.2** version.
Hope it usefull.